# Why there is not the log4j .jar file into the dowloaded version of log4j?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I have to insert **log4j** into a Java application.

I dowloaded it from here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html and I dowload the **log4j-1.2.17.zip** file.

When I unzip it I found a directory that contains some directories (as the one that contains the soruces and the one that contains examples) but there is not the .jar file that I need to insert into my project. Why? Where can I find it?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip file do contain :

- 5 sub folder
- 10 files

And one of the file is log4j-1.2.17.jar

Comment: You can found the jar on maven repository as well : http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar